# Jasmine spyOn - method does not exist in jQuery anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

*Have searched for the answer to this problem on SO and other forums. Didn't find solution.*

I'm running into a problem where Jasmine cannot find a function inside of a jQuery code block, whether the Jasmine code is inside the jQuery function or not.

```
$(function() {
    function foo(param1, param2) {
        // some code
    }

    describe("Foo function", function () {

        spyOn(window, 'foo');

        foo(1, 2);

        it("Should be found by Jasmine", function(){
            expect(window.foo).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
});

Error: foo() method does not exist
```

I have also tried `spyOn($, 'foo')`, `spyOn($.fn, 'foo')` and others.

Also, the following code does not work either.

```
$(function() {
    function foo(param1, param2) {
        // some code
    }
});

describe("Foo function", function () {

    spyOn(window, 'foo');

    foo(1, 2);

    it("Should be found by Jasmine", function(){
        expect(window.foo).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

So how would one make both of these code blocks work (i.e. where the Jasmine code is inside of the jQuery function, and where it is outside of the jQuery function)?

Comment: `foo` is defined inside another anonymous function. Why would it be accessible via `window.foo`?

Comment: I was trying all the solutions provided by other similar questions on the web. Feel free to point me in the direction of the correct answer. Honestly, I don't know what the containing object for an anonymous jQuery function is, so I don't know what object to use.

Answer (score 3):

I hate to answer my own question, but I rather that than other people not learning from my mistakes.

There are 2 issues here:

1. Jasmine needs a containing object
2. You cannot access functions/variable outside the scope of a JS function

1 - Jasmine spies need to use a containing object, and if one can't be found, you just need to make it yourself. So the following code works:

```
// Using Jasmine inside of a jQuery anon function
$(function () {

    function foo() {
        // Some code
    }

    describe("Foo function", function () {

        it("Should be findable by Jasmine", function () {
            var Thing = {}
            Thing.foo = foo;
            spyOn(Thing, 'foo');
            Thing.foo(2)
            expect(Thing.foo).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
});
```

2 - If you have the `describe` block outside of the jQuery anon function, it won't be able to access any values from within the jQuery block, hence the second code example above won't work, no matter what you do.

Comment: `spyOn` requires an object `createSpy` don't. And you are right about scope. Functions defined inside scope are not really testable. Almost like private members in languages with classical oop.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why would you need spies for "private" functions. You can do the following [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LDdZ6/1/).

```
$(function(){
    function foo() {
        return 'foo';
    };

    function baz() {
        return foo();    
    }

    describe('foo', function() { 
        //create a spy and define it to change foo
        foo = jasmine.createSpy().andCallFake(foo);


        it('should be a function', function() {
            expect(typeof foo).toBe('function');             
        });        

        var result = baz(); //call function you want to test

        it('should be called', function() {            
            expect(foo).toHaveBeenCalled(); //check if foo was called by baz   
        });        

        //additional check for return since .andCallThrough won't work
        it('should return foo', function() { 
            expect(result).toBe('foo');    
        })

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to set up your jQuery function differently. Try...

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.foo = function (param1, param2) {
        // some code
    };
}(jQuery));
```

and then your Jasmine script will look like...

```
describe("Foo function", function () {

    var test = spyOn($.fn, 'foo');

    $.fn.foo(1,2);

    it("Should be found by Jasmine", function(){
        expect(test).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(test).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1,2);
    });
});
```

Comment: So your answer dramatically changes my source code. The idea I'm trying for is to perform testing without changing the source code at all. Otherwise I'd need to go through all my code and make it Jasmine-friendly, which is def not a good situation.