# Can't find variable: spyOn

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I am getting issue on jasmine test case promise response handling part

This is my rest service handling method in (wepaCore.api) service:

```
this.auth = function (email, password) {
if (!password || !email) {
  Analytics.trackException(errorMessages.INVALID_EMAIL_PASS, true)

  return $q.reject({
    error: errorMessages.INVALID_INPUT,
    errorDescription: errorMessages.INVALID_EMAIL_PASS
  })
}

return this.makeApiCall('/oauth/token', {
  grant_type: 'password',
  username: email,
  password: password
}, {
  data: {},
  authHeader: 'Basic ' + constants.BASIC_AUTH_TOKEN
})
  .then(function (data) {
    accessToken = data['access_token']
    return accessToken
  }, function (data) {
    return $q.reject(data)
  })
```

}

My test case method:

```
    describe('wepaCore.api', function () {
      var login, $q, deferred

      // load the modules
      beforeEach(module('wepaCore'))

      // inject the services
      beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
        $q = $injector.get('$q')
        deferred = $q.defer()
        login = $injector.get('wepaCore.api')
        // Use a Jasmine Spy to return the deferred promise
        spyOn(login, 'auth').and.returnValue(deferred.promise)
      }))
})
```

Getting "Can't find variable: spyOn" error

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0) wepaCore.api "before each" hook: workFn FAILED
    Can't find variable: spyOn
    e:/wepa/wepa-angular-core-dev/test/unit/apiSpec.js:24:10
    invoke@e:/wepa/wepa-angular-core-dev/bower/angular/angular.js:4665:24
    workFn@e:/wepa/wepa-angular-core-dev/bower/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2965:26
    inject@e:/wepa/wepa-angular-core-dev/bower/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2931:28
    e:/wepa/wepa-angular-core-dev/test/unit/apiSpec.js:19:20
    global code@e:/wepa/wepa-angular-core-dev/test/unit/apiSpec.js:12:9
```

Can you please any one help to resolve this error?

Comment: I imagine it's out of scope, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24748702/jasmine-spyon-method-does-not-exist-in-jquery-anonymous-function

Comment: Yes here i did not use scope in my service file atmd, I write testcase for service files